# Cómo obtener el valor de una variable dentro de una función JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una función y puedo imprimir el contenido de la variable en la vista de la Web:

```
function my_function() {
    var test = document.write(10);
}

my_function();
```

Pero necesito obtener ese valor de test y asignárselo a otra variable que se encuentra dentro del mismo archivo JavaScript:

```
function my_function() {
    var test = 10;
}

var my_new_var = test;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La variable `test` en tu ejercicio esta o existe dentro del contexto de la función `my_function()`, por lo tanto si deseas recuperar ese valor por fuera obtendrás un error como el siguiente:

> "ReferenceError: test is not defined

Si deseas entonces poder recuperar a dicha variable fuera del contexto de la función, podrías considerar:

- Declararla por fuera de cualquier función y asignarle el valor que requiere
- Pasarla dentro de la función como argumento (*y en caso de ser necesario procesar la(s) operacione(s) requerida(s)*)
- No declares a las variables con `var` y en cambio si con `let`
- A la variable que esta fuera de la función iguálala o asígnale el llamado a la función `my_function()` ya que esta retorna lo que valga `test` *o directamente asígnale `test` como valor*, finalmente la función no lleva a cabo acciones con lo que contiene.

```js
let test = 10;

function my_function(elemento) {
  return elemento;
}

let my_new_var = test;

console.log(my_function(test));

console.log(my_new_var);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, déjame intentar y te aviso.

Comment: Funcionó, muchas gracias, pero detecté otro problema y por eso no me leía el contenido de la función... Es posible guardar un JSON en una variable? porque no me lo guarda... En el ejemplo escribí 10 como valor de la variable pero en realidad necesito guardar un JSON

Comment: Lo hago, pero no me muestra el valor: let response = " " function my_function() { $.getJSON("js/img.json", function(datos) { response = JSON.stringify(datos) return response }) } let dataInt = my_function()

Comment: también lo intenté con response = my_function()

Comment: Okey, ya lo publico. Gracias!

Comment: ya la publiqué, gracias: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/356691/c%c3%b3mo-obtener-el-valor-de-una-variable-global-en-el-siguinete-c%c3%b3digo

Answer (score 1):

Las funciones devuelven valor a través de `return`. Prueba del siguiente modo:

```
function my_function() {
    var test = 10;
    return test;
}

var my_new_var = my_function();
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, disculpa no lo había expuesto... También lo había intentado así y tampoco obtengo el valor de la variable.