# Cómo obtener el valor de una variable global en el siguinete código

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código, requiero obtener el valor de la variable `response` y asignársela a `let dataInt = my_function()` y luego utilizarlo en `$.each(dataInt.data,function(key,value){`, el valor que debo obtener es el contenido del archivo JSON externo.

```
let response = " "

function my_function() {
    $.getJSON("js/img.json", function(datos) {
        response = JSON.stringify(datos)
        return response
    })
}
$(window).on('load',function(){
waterFall();

let dataInt = my_function()

$(window).on('scroll',function(){
    if(checkScrollSlide()){
        $.each(dataInt.data,function(key,value){
            var oBox=$('<div>').addClass('box').appendTo($('#main'));
            var oPic=$('<div>').addClass('pic').appendTo(oBox);
            $('<img>').attr('src','images/'+$(value).attr('src')).appendTo(oPic);
        });
        waterFall();
    }
});
});
```

Actualmente me dael siguiente error: TypeError: dataInt is undefined

No está obteniendoel valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `getJSON` de *jQuery* devuelve una `Promise`. La función que se le pasa como argumento es la *callback* que se va a ejecutar cuando la llamada HTTP se complete, por lo que poner el `return` en esa llamada no va a hacer que la función `my_function` retorne ese valor.

Deberás hacer que la función `my_function` espere a esa llamada HTTP y después devuelva el valor obtenido.

Te propongo usar sintaxis `async/await`, pero se podría hacer de otras formas.

```
async function my_function() {
    const datos = await $.getJSON("js/img.json");
    return datos;
}
```

La función `my_function` ahora la declaramos como `async`, de modo que podremos hacer un `await` para esperar a la llamada `$.getJSON`. Una vez tengamos los datos, los devolvemos.

```
$(window).on('load', async function() {
    // ...

    let dataInt = await my_function();

    $(window).on('click', function() {
        // En este punto, dataInt
        // ya tiene valor.
        console.log(dataInt);
    });
});
```

La *callback* que pasamos como *event handler* al evento `load` también la haremos `async`, para poder esperar la respuesta a la función `my_function`.

He quitado el `stringify` a los datos que devolvía el `getJSON` ya que por lo que veo más tarde usas la variable `dataInt` como un objeto. `stringify`, precisamente, *parsea* el *json* a *string*, por lo que `dataInt.data` iba a devolver `undefined`.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, voy a intentarlo y te aviso.

Comment: Excelente, la explicación y funcionó. Muchas gracias nuevamente.